# Sanitize email using express-validator only if it is an email, otherwise ignore

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-validator

I am making an API in which I am taking username and password as req.body so that I can authenticate user.
(In short **login** functionality)
User can enter email or username or mobile number. At backend I want to *normalize* username if it is email. I am doing so because I am *normalizing* email at the time of Registration, therefore I need to check it with *normalized* email.

Want to do something like this: (A short pseudo-code)

```
username <- take input from request  
check if username is email:   
  if yes then *sanitize* username
```

**My Login Rest API For Now:**

```
// Login user
router.post(
  "/login",
  [
    check("username").not().isEmpty().escape(),
    check("password").not().isEmpty().escape(),
  ],
  (req, res, next) => {
    // Finds validation errors and return error object
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    let { username, password } = req.body;
    // Do authentication part
  }
);
```

The above code will work fine if the input is a username but I want to *normalize* email also.

Database content looks like this

```
user : [
  {
    username: 'SOME_MOBILE',
    password: 'SLDUS##$##KDJ'
  },
  {
    username: 'SOME_EMAIL',
    password: 'SLDU$%%##$2342423DJ'
  },
  {
    username: 'my_username',
    password: 'SLDUS##$#fssKDJ'
  }
]
```

**Please help!**
**Thanks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your `username` to be an email check like this:

```
[body("username").notEmpty().escape().if(body("username").isEmail()).nomalizeEmail(), 
body("password").notEmpty().escape()]
```

Comment: I want the username to be either email or a normal username but if I use your solution, It will give error response if I provide a username instead.

Comment: Just edited the post now your "username" field will be sanitized if it's email or not

Comment: Sorry! there was a mistake in understanding between sanitizing and normalizing. Acutally I want to normalize email. Please go through the edited question once again. Edited parts are in italic

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@hapi/joi` package for your validations.
So, try something like this:

```js
const schema = Joi.object().keys({
    username: Joi.string().required(),
    email: Joi.string().email().required()
});
```

**Complete-sample:**

```js
const Joi = require('@hapi/joi');

const schema = Joi.object().keys({

    username: Joi.string().required(),
    email: Joi.string().email().required()
});

let username = 'Roger Brown';
let email = 'roger@example';

let data = { username, email };

Joi.validate(data, schema, (err, value) => {

    if (err) {

        console.log(err.details);

    } else {

        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

If you won't use any third-party packages using `regex` like this:

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
    const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: Sorry! but I am not allowed to use any other package other than express-validator. Please try to suggest me using this package.

Comment: Also it didn't clarify my doubt, I am taking either username or password

Comment: So, Using Regular expressions like the one I added to answer.

Comment: Well that will validate my email, but it won't sanitize it (I want sanitization too)

Answer (score 1):

May be you want to add something else like this:

```
.stripLow()   //Remove some unwanted ascii codes.
.trim()       //Always trim after removing things.
.notEmpty()   
.escape()     //escape after removing.
.isLength({max: 50 })  //check length after adding things.
.normalizeEmail()      //After all normalize and check if it is a email.
.isEmail(),
```

For normal strings i use:

```
check('name', 'Name must be at least 2 characters long, max 35 characters.')
    .stripLow() //Lowest ascii command codes.
    .trim() //trim after taking out things.
    .notEmpty() //check empty.
    .isLength({ min: 2, max: 35 }) //length before and after adding escapes.
    .escape()
    .isLength({ min: 2, max: 35 }), //length before and after adding escapes.
```